# How to make dynamic datepicker? onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hi i want to set the datepicker turn off the backdate if the condition dropdown (#status) == 0 else of them the datepicker is turn on all of the date.
but i have some problem, the datepicker cannot dynamic

```
function validStatus(){
        var status = $('#status').val();
            if(status == 0){
                $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                    //showOn: 'both',
                    //buttonText: 'Show Date',
                    buttonImageOnly: false,
                    //buttonImage: '<c:url value="/images/calendar.png"/>',
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    dateonly:true,
                    yearRange: "-100:+1000",
                    minDate: '0',
                    //changeMonth: true,
                    //changeYear: true,
                    //defaultDate: -(20 * 365), // 20 years ago
                    constrainInput: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });
            }
            else{
                $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                    //showOn: 'both',
                    //buttonText: 'Show Date',
                    buttonImageOnly: false,
                    //buttonImage: '<c:url value="/images/calendar.png"/>',
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    dateonly:true,
                    yearRange: "-100:+1000",
                    //changeMonth: true,
                    //changeYear: true,
                    //defaultDate: -(20 * 365), // 20 years ago
                    constrainInput: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });
            }
            console.log(status)
    }
```

this one the jsp

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Action Plan Status *</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status" onclick="validStatus();" onchange="validStatus();" onkeypress="validStatus();">
                    <option value="${riConstants.ACTION_PLAN_STATUS_OPEN}">Open</option>
                    <option value="${riConstants.ACTION_PLAN_STATUS_INPROGRESS}">In-Progress</option>
                    <option value="${riConstants.ACTION_PLAN_STATUS_CLOSE}">Closed</option>         
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and last the datepicker

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Target Date *</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" id="targetDate" name="targetDate" class="form-control datepicker" readonly="true" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Likely need more info ... is the handling covered by a `document.ready` call somewhere? ... Might be better to create a runnable code snippet by using the `<>` icon on the edit toolbar.

Comment: @PaulT. 
yap, i take the default datepicker(no custom) at the document.ready
but the problem is, the datepicker seems like have a season,
so if i set the default datepicker in document.ready the datepicker at onchange , etc
cannot trigger to customize the datepicker like disable the backdate